# Calling Google Spreadsheets and Vue

Tags: vue.js, google-sheets-api

Good morning,

I am using this library (https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet) to work with Google Sheets, and it seems like the authentication is working properly, but when I am recovering the sheets to work with them, it is throwing me a weird error and I don't know how to fix it.
It's not working the following code (in doc.getInfo):

```
function getInfoAndWorksheets (step) {
          console.log('jj')
          doc.getInfo(function (err, info) {
            console.log('cvcv')
            console.log(info)
            console.log('Loaded doc: ' + info.title + ' by ' + info.author.email)
            var sheet = info.worksheets[0]
            console.log('sheet 1: ' + sheet.title + ' ' + sheet.rowCount + 'x' + sheet.colCount)
            console.log(err)
            step()
          })
        }
```

The error is the next one: err = Error: incorrect header check at Zlib._handle.onerror (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/browserify-zlib/lib/index.js:352:17) at Zlib._error (

You can see the error in the next photo:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501798366536

Comment: Hey, did you manage to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('<Spreadsheet ID>', null, { gzip: false })
```